# How can I sum current system time with integer value as minutes?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create log out time for session time out

and I create a procedure that have 2 Input and 1 Output parameters

one of input values is 'system time' and the other value is number that declare as 'minute'

this is my query but have problem and display this error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

SQL:

```
SELECT to_char((to_date(sysdate,'HH24:MI:SS') + INTERVAL 40 MINUTE,'HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `sysdate` returns the value of date data type, so there is no need
   to explicitly convert `sysdate` to a date data type using
   `to_date()` function.
2. There is also no need of using `to_char()` function if you want to just add a couple of minutes to a value returned by the `sysdate`.
3. The minutes literal in the `INTERVAL 40 MINUTE` construct must be enclosed with single quotes: `INTERVAL '40' MINUTE`

Having said that, you could rewrite your query as follows:

```
SELECT sysdate + INTERVAL '40' MINUTE
  FROM dual;
```

In a procedure, because you cannot include a variable in the `INTERVAL <<variable>> MINUTE` construct, you can use `numtodsinterval()` function.

Moreover, to eliminate unnecessary context switching, you can do all your calculations without querying the `dual` table:

```
p_out_parameter := p_input_date + numtodsinterval(p_input_time, 'minute');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to add a number of minutes onto a date?

```
select sysdate + number_of_minutes/(24*60) from dual;
```